# Unable to post angular form data using web api

Tags: php, angular, webapi

contact.component.html

```
<form class="contact-form" #f = "ngForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="input" [(ngModel)] = "selectedContact.name"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="input" [(ngModel)] = "selectedContact.phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="input" [(ngModel)] = "selectedContact.email"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="required valid" name="message" [(ngModel)] = "selectedContact.message"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="button" (click)="createOrUpdateContact(f)">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private title: Title, private apiService: ApiService) { }

  contacts:  any;
  selectedContact:  any  = {name:null, email:  null, phone: null, message: null};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title.setTitle('Finance | Contact Us');
    this.apiService.readContacts().subscribe((contacts: any)=>{
      this.contacts = contacts;
      console.log(this.contacts);
    })
  }

  createOrUpdateContact(form){
      this.apiService.createContact(form.value).subscribe((contacts: any)=>{
        console.log("Contact created, ", contacts);
      });
  }
}
```

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Contact } from  './model/contact.model';
import { Observable } from  'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  PHP_API_SERVER = "http://localhost";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  readContacts(): Observable<Contact[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Contact[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/financeAPI/read.php`);
  }

  createContact(contact: Contact): Observable<Contact[]>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Contact[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/financeAPI/create.php`, Contact);
  }
}
```

create.php

```
<?php
require 'config/db.php';
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  if(trim($request->name) === '' || trim($request->email) === '' || trim($request->phone) === '' || trim($request->message) === '')
  {
    return http_response_code(400);
  }
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->name));
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->email));
  $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->phone));
  $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->message));
  $s_date = date('Y-m-d');
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `contact`(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`message`,`s_date`) VALUES ('{$name}','{$email}','{$phone}','{$message}','{$s_date}')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    http_response_code(201);
    $policy = [
      'name' => $name,
      'email' => $email,
      'phone' => $phone,
      'message' => $message,
      's_date' => $s_date
    ];
    echo json_encode($policy);
  }
  else
  {
    http_response_code(422);
  }
}
```

I am new in angular and I am simply trying to insert angular form data in mysql using web api. Now, What happen here when I try to read data from database it work perfectly and all data are showing in my console. But when I fill form data then it throw an error as mention below.

`POST http://localhost/financeAPI/create.php 400 (Bad Request)`

`ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: 'http://localhost/financeAPI/create.php', ok: false, …}`

I don't know why this happen? Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank You

Comment: Probably because in your own code you wrote return http_response_code(400);?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am unable to get form field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your submit button try change

`createOrUpdateContact(f)`

to

`createOrUpdateContact(f.value)`

to get the value from  your form

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="button" (click)="createOrUpdateContact(f.value)">Send Message</button>
```

I replicate your code [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swvkfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: when I try to check value is set in `create.php` using `print_r($postdata)` then it show nothing. I have got this error in my console `ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost/financeAPI/create.php', ok: false, …}`